# combine tiles to create image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I use imageMagick to split an image into tiles. I use the following command:

```
convert -crop 100x100 source.png tile%d.png
```

This creates a bunch of tile images. Is there a way to recreate the original image from the tiles?

I'm doing this for different source.png files (of different dimensions), so I don't always know how many tiles there will be for each image (i.e. how many rows/columns).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would be able to do this with a `tile%d.png` since you
wouldn't know how many rows and cols. If the image size wasn't a multiple of
100, you would end up with tiles of a different size. You could then go through
the files checking the size to look for non "full size" tiles. Again this would
breakdown if the original size was 1000x2000.

I think you will need to include the row and column within the file name. You'll
need IM v6.4.8-4 and higher.

```sh
convert source.png -crop 100x100 -set filename:tile \
    "%[fx:page.y/100+1000]_%[fx:page.x/100+1000]" \
    +repage +adjoin "file_tiles_%[filename:tile].png"
```

The magic is `fx:page.x/100+1000`. The `100` needs to match what your crop size
is for x and `1000` is to make the files all line of up to 9999 (so max of 8999
row and columns) or 899 if you don't want to do math to remove the 1000 from the
number.

If you require `tile%d.png`, you could always create both sets. When you go to restore the original you will need to do something like:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x file_tiles_*.png rejoined.png
```

You will need to figure out the number of columns. This can be parsed from the
last one in row 1000...

```sh
ls -1 file_tiles_1000* | tail -1 | sed 's/.*_//g; s/\.png//g; s/^.000*//g'
```

[§ Tile Cropping](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile)